# Substituição de variaveis no corpo da mensagem

Tags: php, regex

Estou criando um sistema de perfil de mensagens, quando o sistema executa uma determinada ação ele pega determinado perfil e dispara a mensagem como *e-mail*, no entanto gostaria que no corpo da mensagem, quando escrito `{{variavel}}` gostaria que ele pegasse o valor da `$variavel` correspondente (de forma automática), no entanto não sei como se chama esse método e ainda não encontrei solução alguma, será que alguém teria condições de dar uma ajudinha?

**Explicação**:

Tenho a seguinte mensagem:

> {{nome}} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry {{email}}

Para substituir esses valores eu teria que fazer da seguinte forma:

```
str_replace("{{nome}}", $nome, $mensagem);
str_replace("{{email}}", $email, $mensagem);
```

Só que eu queria fazer isso de forma que fosse automática.

Comment: Por exemplo: no corpo da mensagem vai conter isso `{{nome}} {{email}}` quero que isso seja trocado pela variavél que vai estar internamente no PHP `$nome $email` com seus respectivos valores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depois de ver a [discussão](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23846/discussion-between-sergio-and-italo-izaac), cheguei as seguintes soluções.

Poderia utilizar a função `preg_replace_callback`.

```php
function preg_parse($template, $vars) {
    $re = '/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/';

    return preg_replace_callback($re, function($match) use($vars) {
        $key = trim($match[1]); //Remove os espaços da direita e esquerda do nome da variável
        return isset($vars[$key]) ? $vars[$key] : $match[0];
    }, $template);
}
```

Ou automatizar a definição das variáveis na solução do @Sergio *(pelo que entendi na discussão era o que estava faltando para você)* .

```php
function replace_parse($template, $vars) {
    $keys   = array_map(function($key) { return '{{'.$key.'}}'; }, array_keys($vars));
    $values = array_values($vars);

    return str_replace($keys, $values, $template);
}
```

Tendo como exemplo o seguinte código.

```php
$vars     = array('nome' => 'foo', 'email' => 'email@domain.com');
$template = '{{nome}} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry {{email}}';

echo preg_parse($template, $vars).PHP_EOL;
echo replace_parse($template, $vars).PHP_EOL;
```

A saída é.

```
foo Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry email@domain.com
foo Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry email@domain.com
```

Porem na função `preg_parse` remove os espaços entre as tags `{{` e `}}`, algo que a `replace_parse` não faz.

Comment: *+1* pelo `preg_replace_callback`. *Off*: Ainda frequenta o Fórum-Invaders? Luis/hacker_wap!

Comment: Eventualmente acesso, uma vez por mês +/- eu dou uma espiada lá, você seria?

Comment: Eu era o *CoderSc*. Que bom vê-lo por aqui. =)

Comment: Quanto tempo em, igualmente.

Comment: O primeiro exemplo parece bem interessante, vou dar uma testada nele. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra alternativa que pode ser utilizada é a [função `strtr`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtr.php), ela tem como objetivo, *traduzir/substituir* determinados caracteres de uma *string*. Veja um exemplo:

```php
$texto = 'Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Inglês';
$traducao = array('Inglês' => 'Português');

echo strtr($texto, $traducao); // Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/pzMEPa)

Supondo que as variáveis `nome` e `email` já estejam definidas com o valor que você quer, faça o seguinte:

```php
$mensagem = '{{nome}} Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing and typesetting industry {{email}}';
$nome  = 'Maria';
$email = 'Maria@foo.bar';

$traducao = array("{{nome}}"  => $nome, 
                  "{{email}}" => $email,
                 );

echo strtr($mensagem, $traducao);
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/f31F3E)

Answer (score 2):

Para substituir dentro de uma string podes usar o [`str_replace();`](http://php.net/str_replace).

A sintaxe é:

> $stringFinal = str_replace("a substituir", "substituto", "string original");

Assim no teu caso poderia ser algo como

```
$email = str_replace({{variavel}}, $variavel, $corpoDoEmail);
```

Também podes usar arrays no str_replace. Desta maneira podes substituir muitos pedaços de cada vez:

```
$pedacos =     array('{{nome}}', '{{mail}}');
$substitutos = array($nome, $email);
$output  =     str_replace($pedacos , $substitutos , $corpoDoEmail);
```

Comment: isso dá certo, porém se eu tiver 100 variáveis terei de fazer isso para cada uma das 100. Queria que fosse de forma automática. Já tentei com o `preg_replace()` mas não obtive nenhum resultado.

Comment: @ItaloIzaac podes explicar melhor na pergunta e juntar um exemplo? 100 variáveis diferentes no texto ou fazer a substituição para 100 textos diferentes?

Comment: @ItaloIzaac editei a resposta.

Comment: Eu dei uma pequena explicação no original, dê uma olhada. Obrigado desde já por tentar ajudar!

Comment: @ItaloIzaac o que queres dizer "de forma automática"? fazendo isso com arrays no `str_replace` é tb automático...

Comment: Mas eu teria que colocar cada uma das variaveis dentro do array ... de forma automática, sem eu precisar ter de adicionar mais uma variavel sempre que eu alterar uma dela.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23846/discussion-between-sergio-and-italo-izaac).